# How to convert directory listing to text format in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to know how I can change the directry listing to text format.

Forexample :-

If I go to

```
 www.example.com/directry
```

then it should show me listing of files and directory in text . How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To change the content_type of directory listing to  text/plain  ,

Add the following line to your htaccess file :

```
IndexOptions Type=text/plain
```

**Source :** http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html

Comment: Perfect ,thank you! It works but how can I change it to previous format now?

Comment: Just Change the type=text/plain **to** type=text/html